# What meaning does it have when I put a space within a range quantifier in a regex?

Tags: ruby, regex, literals

Putting a space within a range quantifier in a regex seems syntactically valid:

```
/.{1, 2}/ # => /.{1, 2}/
```

However, such space seems to alter the behaviour compared to when there is no such space:

```
"a" =~ /.{1,2}/ # => 0
"a" =~ /.{1, 2}/ # => nil
```

What would be the meaning of a regex with space within a range like `/.{1, 2}/`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
/.{1, 2}/
```

matches `"a{1, 2}"`. Though it is syntactically valid, the `{1, 2}` stops being a *limiting quantifier*.

Once a `space` appears between the comma and the `max` numeric value, `{1, 2}` behaves as a `literal` string match.

Comment: As far as I know, in some old versions of some language you could use a space inside the limiting quantifier and it was ignored. I cannot remember that language now. There was such an SO question before, and some comment mentioned that fact.

Comment: This space inside can be ignored if a VERBOSE flag is used, BTW, but the special meaning will still be lost.

Comment: @sawa if u use `re.Verbose` it will match `a{1,2}`.the special meaning is lost in all cases

Comment: Not surprisingly, `"a{1, 2}" =~ /.{1, 2}/x #=> nil`, `x` being the *extended/free-spacing* regex definition mode.